# Appcelerator Titanium + iOS + webview - change CSS for buttons on touch / on click

Tags: ios, css, webview, titanium, appcelerator

I'm using Appcelerator Titanium + iOS and I have a problem. I'm using webview without top / bottom shadow so it looks like it's not a webview, but this is not a problem - the problem is, I have some buttons

```
<a href="#" onclick="click()">button</a>
```

And I would like to add into CSS action on touch / on click. How can I do that ? I tried to use **a:hover** or **a:active** but it doesn't work correctly. I want to change background on touching / clicking buttons. Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Just use the `ontouchend` event instead of `onclick`

Answer (score 0):

Well, this isn't really an Appcelerator problem, as much as a simple html/javascript problem. Since your code is happening within a web view, it should have a standard html document structure. Have you tried something like this?

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.backgroundColor='someColor';">button</a>
```

Comment: Honestly, I've used jquery, but it doesn't work as I want:

http://jsfiddle.net/x8a4S/10/

Comment: What is your desired behaviour? Your jsfiddle code seems to be working fine?